# WMIC remote request on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wmic

I'm trying to use CMD command with python script for my small "autoinstall" project.

Command I want to use:

```
WMIC /NODE:'kv-c112-11' OS get Caption
```

What I've got:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['WMIC', '/NODE:\"kv-c112-11\"', 'OS', 'get', 'Caption'])
result = str(result)
print(result)
```

In stdout I see:

```
b''
```

I expect to see:

```
b'Caption                                                          \r\r\n\x8c\xa0\xa9\xaa\xe0\xae\xe1\xae\xe4\xe2 Windows 10 \x8a\xae\xe0\xaf\xae\xe0\xa0\xe2\xa8\xa2\xad\xa0\xef LTSC  \r\r\n\r\r\n'
```

If I use this code locally, it works:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['WMIC','OS','get','Caption'])
```

What am I doing wrong?